# React Native working with NativeBase: WARN NativeBase: The contrast ratio of 1:1 for darkText on transparent

Tags: react-native, native-base, wcag

I'm programming a React Native App using NativeBase.io

In my app where I use NativeBase I am getting the following error.....how do I fix this?

Here is the error:

> WARN  NativeBase: The contrast ratio of 1:1 for darkText on
> transparent falls below the WCAG recommended absolute minimum contrast
> ratio of 3:1.
> https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#visual-audio-contrast-contrast
> InputBase@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:193716:28
> RCTView View
> @http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:150602:25
> Box@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:191721:24
> InputAdvance@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:193858:33
> Input@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:193651:24
> RCTView View
> @http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:150602:25
> Box@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:191721:24
> UserListScreen@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:223372:50
> StaticContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:234421:17
> EnsureSingleNavigator@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:230142:24
> SceneView@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:234305:22
> RCTView View RCTView View
> Background@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:236500:21
> Screen@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:237782:108
> RNSScreen
> AnimatedComponent@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:67782:80
> AnimatedComponentWrapper
> Screen@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:238098:36
> MaybeScreen@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:237954:24
> RNSScreenContainer
> ScreenContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:238211:31
> MaybeScreenContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:237923:23
> RCTView View
> SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:237712:24
> BottomTabView@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:226059:30
> @http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:234075:24
> BottomTabNavigator@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:225921:32
> EnsureSingleNavigator@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:230142:24
> BaseNavigationContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:229651:28
> ThemeProvider@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:235690:21
> NavigationContainerInner@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:235550:26
> SSRProvider@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:193075:25
> ToastProvider@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:204142:24
> PortalProvider@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:201313:50
> HybridProvider@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:214396:24
> RNCSafeAreaProvider
> SafeAreaProvider@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:154679:24
> NativeBaseConfigProviderProvider@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:148509:27
> ThemeProvider@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:145479:38
> NativeBaseProvider@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:214282:33
> Provider@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:216267:21
> App@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:108372:54
> RCTView View RCTView View
> AppContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:75251:36
> DanceConnectyCube(RootComponent)@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.DanceConnectyCube:82468:28
> undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had the same warning. I tried some colour changes in my components and I found the problem, **input bg colour** is `white` and also my view background is `"light.100"`. I changed my colour to `"transparent"` or `"muted.500"` and the warning disappeared. This warning allows us to **better manage colours for dark mode**.

Answer (score 2):

If you are following the design from your designer, And you can't change that color, you can skip the warning with LogBox.

Add below lines to your `index.js` file

```
import {LogBox} from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['NativeBase:']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was use of `variant="outline"` prop to get an outlined button. Changing colours or colour-schemes didn't worked for me. Using `borderWidth: 1` as style prop instead, made the error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with an outline button. The warning "The contrast ratio of 1:1 for darkText on *transparent*" is referring to the background color of the button.

Here's a dark-on-white, light-on-black outline button that works in both light and dark modes, without hard-coding color values (other than black and white):

```
import { useContrastText } from 'native-base';

const bgLight = "white";
const bgDark = "black";
const lightContrastColor = useContrastText(bgLight);
const darkContrastColor = useContrastText(bgDark);

<Button
    variant="outline"
    colorScheme="light"
    _light={{ bg: bgLight, borderColor: lightContrastColor, _text: { color: lightContrastColor } }}
    _dark={{ bg: bgDark, borderColor: darkContrastColor, _text: { color: darkContrastColor } }}
    onPress={() => null}>Lorem Ipsum</Button>
```